# What is the right way to pick only 'query_result' from a registered output coming out of community.postgresql.postgresql_query?

Tags: postgresql, ansible

I am a beginner with ansible.

In my playbook I am trying to run a query on a database on a remote host and then to save the query result as an [ansible fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html), to be later passed to another host as [ansible hostvar](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html)

```
- name: query_X
  community.postgresql.postgresql_query:
    login_host: '{{ db_host }}'
    login_user: '{{ db_username }}'
    login_password: '{{ db_password }}'
    db: '{{ db_database }}'
    port: '{{ db_database_port }}'
    query: "{{ lookup('template', 'my_query.sql.j2') }}"

  register: query_X_results

- name: show query_X_results output
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: |
      results of query X:       {{ query_X_results }}
```

Until here everything runs fine: `query_X_results` contains the whole ansible data structure of the accomplished task.

Now I just want to save the `query_result` , which in my case is

```
'query_result': [{'my_column': 5198}]
```

In order to do that, I have setup the following task.

```
- name: save query_X_results output
  set_fact:
      query_X_results:       "{{ query_X_results['query_result']          }}"
```

But as it runs, it throws this error

```
"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute `'query_result'`.
```

I have also tryed to run

```
- name: save query_X_results output
  set_fact:
      query_X_results:       "{{ query_X_results.query_result         }}"
```

but the error remains.

So what is the right way to extract only `'query_result'` from `query_X_results` ?

Note: I'd prefer not to use the module `community.general.json_query`, e.g.

```
community.general.json_query(query_result)
```

### update

This is the output of `show query_X_results output` task

```
show query_X_results output...
  target_machine ok: {

    "changed": false,

    "msg": "results of query X:         {'changed': False, 'rowcount': 1, 'query_list': ['select select * from table;\\n'], 'query_all_results': [[{'my_column': 9289}]], 'query': 'select select * from table;\\n', 'query_result': [{'my_column': 9289}], 'statusmessage': 'SELECT 1', 'ansible_facts': {'discovered_interpreter_python': '/usr/bin/python'}, 'deprecations': [{'msg': 'Distribution Ubuntu 16.04 on host target_machine should use /usr/bin/python3, but is using /usr/bin/python for backward compatibility with prior Ansible releases. A future Ansible release will default to using the discovered platform python for this host. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information', 'version': '2.12'}], 'failed': False}\n"

}
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of the `ansible.builtin.debug` task? `query_X_results` seems to be a list. Lists are accessed via index `query_X_results[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

I have found out that in task `save query_X_results output` I was not actually saving (setting facts) `query_X_results.query_result` , but another variable.

So the error message

```
"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute `'query_result'`.
```

was indicated that variable `query_X_results` was undefined, and so, even `'query_result'` was undefined.